# Unable to launch Jupyter lab from cmd in windows 7

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, jupyter-lab, miniconda

The command 'jupyter lab' usually works fine in cmd. But today it isn't. I uninstall and reinstalled all jupyter components but no gain. Jupyter notebook seems to be working though.

> C:\Users\Sarth.choudhary>jupyter lab 
>   Cannot open D:\Programs\Miniconda3\Scripts\jupyter-lab-script.py

I looked into the miniconda directory, jupyter-lab-script.py is indeed missing. I don't have this file anywhere in the miniconda directory.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The missing `my-env/Scripts/jupyter-lab-script.py` is just a very simple launch script for the `jupyterlab.labapp.main` function.

So just create `my-env/Scripts/jupyter-lab-script.py` containing the following code and the problem is solved (no need to create a whole new environment to copy from):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from jupyterlab.labapp import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

(**NOTE:** I copy-pasted from `my-env/Scripts/jupyter-notebook-script.py` and replaced the imported module by the correct `jupyterlab.labapp`. Didn't check if that is exactly the same as the original, but it works the same.)

Comment: Hi, 
A lot has changed since the original post, my old laptop died so I had to buy a new one with Windows 10. Everything works fine except that now I have to activate base environment every time I open command prompt terminal. Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Not sure if that answers your question, but try `conda config --set auto_activate_base true` (requires conda >= 4.6).

Answer (score 0):

I created another environment and installed jupyter lab in it. Ensured everything worked fine. Copied the missing file and pasted it in the base env folder. After making sure that I can launch Jupiter lab from base environment I removed the new environment.
I think antivirus must have deleted that file so I created an exception in antivirus.